# Why Is Ubuntu So Slow On My More Than Capable System

Tags: boot, drivers, graphics, amd-graphics

I have a Dell Inspiron 3135 that is custom built straight from the Dell site.
The specs are: [My Specs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3qmfu.png)

As you can see I have 8gb of ram, a very powerful processor, more than capable graphics processor. I have tried all the Ubuntu versions from 12.04 to 16.10, all of them are terribly slow, laggy, and can barely run any video from YouTube.

Windows 10 is extremely fast, faster than my desktop with 16gb ram, 1tb hard drive, amd a10, and intel hd graphics. But Ubuntu is so so so so slow.

I have installed the graphics driver, and it caused problems, I tried not installing it, and Ubuntu is so laggy. 
What can I do? I do not want to run Windows 10, I want to run Ubuntu but I use this PC for school, so it has to be fast. Also my touchpad does not work, it is erratic and wont respond most of the time.

Please help, I love Ubuntu and all the things I can do, but the slowness booting up and using the OS, and unreliable shut down is really hard.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: According to your specs you have a 1Ghz CPU? Anyway, this is likely an AMD issue, which driver did you install? You need this one these days http://support.amd.com/en-us/kb-articles/Pages/AMD-Radeon-GPU-PRO-Linux-Beta-Driver%E2%80%93Release-Notes.aspx and at least Ubuntu 16.04

Comment: Your issue most likely stems from the fact that you have an AMD graphics card. I suggest that you try Xubuntu instead, which has a less graphic intensive desktop, or get an Nvidia GPU.

Comment: I googled around for your GPU, it should work, so this is odd. Try another DE, like Gnome, or KDE, and see if it change anything.

Comment: By the way, about the video — it is slow because it didn't use GPU at all, so given you have 1Ghz CPU, no surprise. IIRC in Chromium acceleration was disabled in compile time because it caused problems with some drivers in the past, so you may try using [this PPA](https://launchpad.net/~saiarcot895/+archive/ubuntu/chromium-dev) — there acceleration is enabled; you have to also install vaapi driver. On aside note, α) use the latest system to have better performance, and β) out of curiosity you can compare OpenGL performance on Windows and Linux with GPUTest benchmark.

Comment: That AMD-A6 is **not** a *"very powerful processor"*

Comment: Ok I have tried Gnome, and all of the other the DEs, the same problem occurs. My processor is pretty powerful for a laptop. I went to the Additional Drivers application and installed the proprietary drivers, but on reboot all I get is the terminal or bash. I am really good with computers and have fixed all of them but this. The AMD driver just doesn't work. Just to let you know, 12.04 works great, but it doesn't have all the PPAs I need. Plus I need to be up to date. I used to have an Intel machine that had 512mb of ram, a weak graphics card and processor. It ran Ubuntu lightning fast.

Comment: @AndroidDev It is a pretty powerful processor for a 4-5 year old laptop, it was good choice at the time because it was only $300 and very powerful. Since I develop, I need Ubuntu for some of the tools, but it also needs to be fast. I have doubled the ram, bought a faster hard drive, but I cannot upgrade the APU or GPU. I do not have any money to buy an Intel machine

Comment: @MiNicknameisKeegirl - I never said it was a *weak* CPU...